# Making distinct selections from the given list

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to make a team of unique members from the given set I have. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
        /* Putting all team-mates in HashMap */

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("a", 1);
        map.put("b", 2);
        map.put("c", 3);
        map.put("d", 4);

        /* Printing out the random name and the Unique number with it*/

        List<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
        List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
        System.out.println("The Team members are :");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(valuesList.size());
            Integer randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);
            String randomKey = keyList.get(randomIndex);
            System.out.println(randomValue+" "+randomKey);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get duplication in my list, do I use Collections.shuffle(valuesList)?

Thank You.

Comment: `import java.lang.*;` not required... , `java.lang.Exception` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a,b,c,d is all you are after, this is how I would do it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
        /* Putting all team-mates in a List*/

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");

        /* Printing out the random name */

        System.out.println("The Team members are :");
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
            //Integer randomValue = valuesList.get(randomIndex);
            String randomValue = list.remove(randomIndex);
            //String randomKey = keyList.get(randomIndex);
            System.out.println(randomValue);
        }
    }
}
```

removing chosen elements from the list once chosen will make sure they don't reappear.

Fewer lines too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same number randomly twice, so `Collections.shuffle(...)` should do.

Comment: Yes, shuffle the collection and print it in the resulting order. Alternatively, shuffle a list of keys and use them, if reordering a collection is not desirable.

Comment: Collections.shuffle(ValuesList) seems to work with valuesList.remove(randomIndex)